# run time error with coding settings for android app

Tags: android, settings

I am developing an Android app that has the capability to sort movies by most popular or top rated from the moviedb.org api.  The app is supposed to get new data from the server when the setting is changed.  This is not working.  Here is my code please help me through it:

```
//MainActivity.java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if(savedInstanceState==null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,new MainActivityFragment()).commit();
    }

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }

//SettingsActivity.java
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_order_key)));
}

public void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference){
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    onPreferenceChange(preference, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(),""));
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
    String stringValue=value.toString();
    if(preference instanceof ListPreference){
        ListPreference listPreference=(ListPreference)preference;
        int prefIndex=listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if(prefIndex>=0){
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
    }else {
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
    }
    return true;
}
//MainActivityFragment.java
public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    if (getActivity()!=null){
        ArrayList<String>arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
        PosterAdapter imageAdapter=new PosterAdapter(getActivity(),arrayList,deviceWidth);
        imageGridView=(GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_grid_view);
        imageGridView.setColumnWidth(deviceWidth);
        imageGridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
    imageGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class).putExtra("overview", overview.get(position))
                    .putExtra("poster", images.get(position))
                    .putExtra("title", title.get(position))
                    .putExtra("date", date.get(position))
                    .putExtra("rating", rating.get(position));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
private class PreferenceChangeListener implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        imageGridView.setAdapter(null);
        onStart();
    }
}
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    preferenceChangeListener=new PreferenceChangeListener();
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
    if (sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_order_key),"").equals(R.string.pref_order_most_popular)){
        sortByPopular=true;
    }else if (sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_order_key),"").equals(R.string.pref_order_top_rated)){
        sortByPopular=false;
    }
        ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader();
    if (isInternetAvailable()) {
        imageLoader.execute();
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"async task completed");
    }else {
        TextView textView=new TextView(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout);
        textView.setText("There is no Internet service");
        if (relativeLayout.getChildCount()==1){
            relativeLayout.addView(textView);
        }
        imageGridView.setVisibility(GridView.GONE);
    }
}
public boolean isInternetAvailable(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo !=null&&networkInfo.isConnected();
}
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<String>>{


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (true){
            try {
                images=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getPathsFromURL(sortByPopular)));
                return images;
            }catch (Exception e){
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String>results){
        if (results!=null&&getActivity()!=null){
            PosterAdapter posterAdapter=new PosterAdapter(getActivity(),results,deviceWidth);
            imageGridView.setAdapter(posterAdapter);
        }
    }
    public String[] getPathsFromURL(boolean sorting){

        while (true){
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
            String JSONResult;
            try {
                if (sortByPopular){
                    url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=281ad0257e71bca17a21b42c9fee7304";
                }else {
                    url="http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=vote_average.desc&vote_count.gte=500&api_key=281ad0257e71bca17a21b42c9fee7304";
                }
                URL url1=new URL(url);
                httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream=httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream==null){
                    return null;
                }
                bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String data;
                while ((data=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    stringBuffer.append(data+"\n");
                }
                if (stringBuffer.length()==0){
                    return null;
                }
                JSONResult=stringBuffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,JSONResult);
                try {
                    overview=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getStringsFromAPI(JSONResult, "overview")));
                    title=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getStringsFromAPI(JSONResult, "original_title")));
                    rating=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getStringsFromAPI(JSONResult, "vote_average")));
                    date=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getStringsFromAPI(JSONResult, "release_date")));
                    return getDataFromJSON(JSONResult);
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    return null;
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                continue;
            }finally {
                if (httpURLConnection!=null){
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (bufferedReader!=null){
                    try {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    }catch (final IOException e){

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    public String[] getStringsFromAPI(String JSONStringParameter,String parameter) throws JSONException{
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(JSONStringParameter);
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        String[] results=new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject poster=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            if (parameter.equals("vote_average")){
                Double decimalNumber=poster.getDouble("vote_average");
                String userRating=Double.toString(decimalNumber)+"/10";
                results[i]=userRating;
            }
            String posterPath=poster.getString(parameter);
            results[i]=posterPath;
        }
        return results;
    }
    public String[] getDataFromJSON(String JSONStringParameter)throws JSONException{
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(JSONStringParameter);
        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
        String[] results=new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject poster=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String posterPath=poster.getString("poster_path");
            results[i]=posterPath;
        }
        return results;
    }
//PosterAdapter.java
 private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private int posterWidth;

public PosterAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<String> filePaths,int a){
    context=c;
    arrayList=filePaths;
    posterWidth=a;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView image;
    if (convertView==null){
        image=new ImageView(context);
    }else {
        image=(ImageView)convertView;
    }
    String url = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + arrayList.get(position);
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(image);
    return image;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to another developer and it appears that my code is accurate and there is a bug that the other developer is trying to figure out.  I'll keep you guys posted.  Thank you for your help.